# I found two black spot on my MacBook Air screen. Is that a defective pixel?

Tags: macbook, macbook-air, dead-pixel, apple

I'm using MacBook Air A2337 since 2022. Just about a week ago, I noticed a black spot on my laptop's screen. Yesterday I found another one. I also tried to boot my laptop in safe mode. The spot is still there. Is there anything I should aware of?

[Image of 1st black spot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CU6vZ.jpg)

[Image of 2nd black spot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At39V.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the screen? With a computer this new, have you contacted for warranty service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A certain number of dead pixels are expected , and the number of pixels is likely [specified by the manufacturer](https://www.wise-geek.com/what-is-a-dead-pixel-policy.htm), though that info is not widely published.

That said, the two images look like *groups* of about six pixels, which is *not* expected by chance. Some possible causes:

- Dirt on the screen
- Damage from a pulsed laser, e.g., this [DIY project](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-make-a-burning-laser-for-CHEAP/) or a 3-D printer or scribe.
- Electrostatic discharge (ESD), e.g., from a piezo lighter element.

Hopefully, it's just dirt.